# При нажатии кнопки формы ничего не происходит

Tags: php, html

PHP html в разных файлах. Нужно по нажатию кнопки `submit` выполнить php. Но ничего не происходит

html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>jjjh</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <form id="upload-container" method="POST" action="index.php">
          <div>
               <input id="file-input" type="file" name="file">
          </div>
          <div>
                <input type="button" name = "submit" value=" Преобразовать ">
          </div>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    include ('выбор.html');

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    include ('наша.php');
    echo '<pre>';
    $kml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
    foreach ($kml->Document->Folder->Placemark as $Placemark) {

            echo $Placemark->MultiGeometry->Polygon->outerBoundaryIs->LinearRing->coordinates, PHP_EOL;

        foreach ( $Placemark->ExtendedData->SchemaData as $SchemaData ) {
            foreach ( $SchemaData as $SimpleData ) {
                $name = $SimpleData->attributes()->name;
                if ( $name == 'TITLE' || $name == 'DESCRIPTIO' || $name == 'SHAPE_Area') {
                    echo '<pre>';
                    echo $SimpleData.PHP_EOL;
                    echo '</pre>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: `<input type="submit" ...>` - отправляет форму на сервер для обработки

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @РустамГимранов думаю, стоит оформить как ответ

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk, лучше вопрос удалить, чем писать пару абзацев про `type="submit"`. )))

Comment: @РустамГимранов это, кстати, популярный вопрос в интернете :)

Answer (score 0):

Для отправки данных формы на сервер, необходимо указать тип кнопки как `type="submit"`.

Пример использования с `button` ([Атрибут type](http://htmlbook.ru/html/button/type)):

```
  <form action="handler.php">
   <p><input type="text" name="user"></p> 
   <p><button type="submit">Отправить форму</button></p>
  </form>
```

Пример использования с `input` ([Атрибут type](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/type)):

```
  <form action="handler.php">
   <p><input type="text" name="user"></p> 
   <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить форму"></p>
  </form>
```